# List apps with access to your Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, permission, authentication

Since you can now login to certain OSX/iOS apps using your Apple ID credentials rather than with an application-specific account, is there a way to list all of the apps you have granted access to and edit their permissions (something like what Google does when you authenticate using your Google credentials)?

Comment: To which applications/apps do you log in using your Apple ID? Can you list some examples?

Comment: @patrix Day One 2 would be an example: https://dayone.me/user/login And that's actually the only one I can think of right now :D

Comment: If I understand this correctly, Day One uses the Apple ID for authentication only and there are no access rights to anything in your account involved in that (kind of like OpenID). But let's see whether somebody has a more thorough and fact-based explanation for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question: this is currently not possible, there is no way to see what apps / services you have authenticated with using your Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, Go to Settings > Your name > iCloud > List of apps.

You can turn on / off any of the apps using your Apple ID

Comment: This lists all apps that use your iCloud account for storage, not the apps you have logged in using your Apple ID, SSO style. The two lists are not necessarily the same.

Comment: There are 2 sections `Apps Using iCloud` and another section `Allow apps to store documents and data in iCloud`.

Comment: Still not the same thing. Look at this: https://dayone.me/user/login I can't see anywhere that I logged in to day one with my Apple ID. Twitter and Facebook have this feature. This is the feature that is missing. Day One appears in those lists alongside other apps I have NOT logged into using my Apple ID.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly login into an app with Apple ID. Apple ID is on your device, apps can associate with your Apple ID. They don't have access to your data unless you grant them specific access. All apps using your Apple ID (though you haven't logged into that app with an Apple ID) will be listed there. It is up to you to turn on / off those apps. Apps use this feature to sync the app data for a specific user across the user's devices

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if it is the same thing. But there is a 'Manage apps that can look you up' section in the advanced settings on [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/#settings). Here you have a [support article](https://help.apple.com/icloud/#mmbffe88bb42) about it.

Could not find anything else in iCloud that comes close. However it is a great feature request! You can give [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/icloud.html) about this to Apple.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same thing, to me this feature sounds like if another user is using the same app as you, they can look you up from the app using your Apple ID.

Comment: The question is, are you logged in with your Apple ID in that app. If they can look you up.. you given your Apple ID someway...

Comment: The point is, you can revoke the permission to look you up in that setting section you linked to, but you could still be logging in to the app with your Apple ID, so I think the two are not the same thing. I really think that the option to see all places where you are using your Apple ID to login to something is missing at the moment.

Comment: In this setting you can only hide yourself from others finding you in apps that are using your Apple ID. I agree it is not the same thing and this function is missing at the moment. I highly recommend you to send Apple a feature request through the feedback form.

Answer (score -1):

If you logged into the app using your Apple ID and password directly (in the app itself / on its website, not on apple.com), then you cannot see a list, because those apps are signing in **as you**.

If you generated an app-specific password (which is needed for things like Mail and Calendar apps that connect to your iCloud) **or** if you used "Sign in with Apple" (where you click a link that sends you to apple.com to sign in), you can view a list of passwords at https://appleid.apple.com. Choose either "Sign in with Apple" or "App-Specific Passwords" to see the respective lists.